# Boost rank for special type of document

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index with 2 types of document: `District` and `Street`. I would like to boost rank of `District` documents.

Is there any way to do that without the `script` option?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `custom_filters_score` to boost documents matching a filter, and your filter can be a `type`-filter.

Here's a runnable example you can play with: https://www.found.no/play/gist/8744808

```
#!/bin/bash

export ELASTICSEARCH_ENDPOINT="http://localhost:9200"

# Index documents
curl -XPOST "$ELASTICSEARCH_ENDPOINT/_bulk?refresh=true" -d '
{"index":{"_index":"play","_type":"district"}}
{"title":"there"}
{"index":{"_index":"play","_type":"street"}}
{"title":"there"}
'

# Do searches

curl -XPOST "$ELASTICSEARCH_ENDPOINT/_search?pretty" -d '
{
    "query": {
        "custom_filters_score": {
            "query": {
                "match": {
                    "title": {
                        "query": "there"
                    }
                }
            },
            "filters": [
                {
                    "boost": 2,
                    "filter": {
                        "type": {
                            "value": "district"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
'
```